# MySQL Query to display ingredients

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables

```
mysql> select * from drink;
+----+--------------+----------+---------+
| id | name         | location | alcohol |
+----+--------------+----------+---------+
|  1 | Ginger Ale   |       13 |       0 |
|  2 | Whiskey      |        1 |       1 |
|  3 | Vodka        |        2 |       1 |
|  4 | Rum          |        3 |       1 |
|  5 | Gin          |        4 |       1 |
|  6 | Tequila      |        5 |       1 |
|  7 | Triple Sec   |        6 |       1 |
|  8 | Cola         |       14 |       0 |
| 10 | Cherry Vodka |        7 |       1 |
| 11 | Sprite       |       15 |       0 |
| 12 | Sour Mix     |        0 |       0 |
| 13 | Lemon Juice  |        0 |       0 |
| 14 | Lime Juice   |        0 |       0 |
| 15 | Grenadine    |        0 |       0 |
| 16 | Orange Juice |       16 |       0 |
+----+--------------+----------+---------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from cocktail;
+----+-------+----------------------------------+
| id | name  | comment                          |
+----+-------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | Item1 | Whiskey Ginger                   |
|  2 | Item2 | Screwdriver                      |
|  3 | Item3 | Cherry Vodka and Sprite          |
|  4 | Item4 | Bartender's Long Island Iced Tea |
|  5 | Item5 | Long Island Iced Tea             |
|  6 | Item6 | Gin and Sin                      |
+----+-------+----------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mix;
+----+---------+------------+--------+
| id | drinkID | cocktailID | ounces |
+----+---------+------------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |          1 |   4.00 |
|  2 |       2 |          1 |   1.00 |
|  9 |      10 |          3 |   1.00 |
| 10 |      11 |          3 |   4.00 |
| 11 |       5 |          4 |   0.75 |
| 12 |       4 |          4 |   0.75 |
| 13 |       6 |          4 |   0.75 |
| 14 |       3 |          4 |   0.75 |
| 15 |       7 |          4 |   1.00 |
| 16 |      12 |          4 |   1.00 |
| 17 |       8 |          4 |   1.00 |
| 18 |       3 |          5 |   0.75 |
| 19 |       5 |          5 |   0.75 |
| 20 |       4 |          5 |   0.75 |
| 21 |       6 |          5 |   0.75 |
| 22 |      12 |          5 |   2.00 |
| 23 |       8 |          5 |   1.00 |
| 24 |       7 |          5 |   1.00 |
| 25 |       5 |          6 |   2.00 |
| 26 |      13 |          6 |   2.00 |
| 27 |      15 |          6 |   2.00 |
| 28 |      16 |          6 |   2.00 |
| 33 |       3 |          2 |   1.50 |
| 34 |      16 |          2 |   4.00 |
+----+---------+------------+--------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

From these tables I want to create a joined table that has the ID, Comment, Ingredient Name, and Number of ounces.

So far I have this query but I keep getting errors and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
 select cocktail.comment
      , drink.name
      , mix.ounces 
   from cocktail 
   join mix 
     on mix.drinkID = drink.ID 
   join cocktail  
     on mix.cocktailID = cocktail.id;
```

I think that there is something wrong with my join statement but the MySQL error is ambiguous to me

```
ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'cocktail'
```

Would someone be able to provide me some guidance? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide table structures?

Comment: Note that the surrogate id on the mix table serves no practical purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're query is calling the `cocktail` table twice.  If you want to do that you need to use an alias to give unique names to the calls, but it looks like you're missing the `JOIN` to the `drink` table. It seems like you want:

```
select 
  c.comment, 
  d.name, 
  m.ounces 
from drink d 
inner join mix m
  on m.drinkID = d.ID 
inner join cocktail c
  on m.cocktailID = c.id;
```

Here is a [demo](http://rextester.com/SXKBM84515). This difference with this version and your version is it includes a call to the `drink` table to get the name of the ingredient.